# iOS Printing with image and text

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to print an image and some text above it. When I print the image it takes up the entire page I only want it in the center and about 320 x 480 pix. Someone told me I needed to use rects but I do not know how to do this. The code below is what I have so far, it just prints the image but it has no size constraints. Thank You.

```
-(void)sendToPrinter{
UIPrintInteractionController *print = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

if(!print){

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Print Unavailable!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    return;
}


pageSize = print.printPaper.paperSize;
pageSize = CGSizeMake(print.printFormatter.printPageRenderer.printableRect.size.width, print.printFormatter.printPageRenderer.printableRect.size.height);



NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *projectTitle = [data stringForKey:@"pName1"];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", projectTitle];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];


NSData *finalImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];


print.delegate = self;
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.jobName = [[(PageView *)[self view] representedPage] title];
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
print.printInfo = printInfo;
print.showsPageRange = YES;
print.printingItem = finalImageData;
UIViewPrintFormatter *viewFormatter = [self.view viewPrintFormatter];
viewFormatter.startPage = 0;

print.printFormatter = viewFormatter;

UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if(!completed && error){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Print Unavailable!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
};

[print presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
- (void) drawText{
 CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 

NSString *textToDraw = @"Lorem ipsum ";


UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font
                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) 
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 350.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

[textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect 
              withFont:font
         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
             alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
}

- (void) drawImage{

//paint chart

UIImage* chartImage = [self getUIImageScreenShot];;

[chartImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - chartImage.size.width/2)/2, 70, chartImage.size.width/2, chartImage.size.height/2)];
//[chartImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - chartImage.size.width/2)/2, 70, chartImage.size.width/2, chartImage.size.height/2)];}

}
- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath{
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

//NSInteger currentPage = 0;
BOOL done = NO;
do 
{
    //Start a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);


    //Draw some text for the page.
    [self drawText];

    //Draw an image
    [self drawImage];

    done = YES;
} 
while (!done);

// Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

seems like you are only adding the picture to the printing item

```
print.printingItem = imageData;
```

have you tried creating the whole "picture" of what you want printed out (including the text and stuff) and sending that to the printer instead?

Comment: I don't know how to that's what I need help with.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to insert a simple image into and text into PDF, might point you in the right direction

```
- (IBAction)generatePdfButtonPressed:(id)sender{
pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792);

NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *projectTitle = [data stringForKey:@"pName1"];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", projectTitle];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

[self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];}
```

and then...

```
- (void) drawText{
CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 

NSString *textToDraw = @"Lorem ipsum ";


UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font
                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) 
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 350.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

[textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect 
              withFont:font
         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
             alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
}

- (void) drawImage{

//paint chart
NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"chartImageP1"];
UIImage* chartImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

[chartImageBack drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - chartImageBack.size.width/2)/2, 70, chartImageBack.size.width/2, chartImageBack.size.height/2)];
[chartImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - chartImage.size.width/2)/2, 70, chartImage.size.width/2, chartImage.size.height/2)];}

- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath{
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

NSInteger currentPage = 0;
BOOL done = NO;
do 
{
    //Start a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);


    //Draw some text for the page.
    [self drawText];

    //Draw an image
    [self drawImage];

    done = YES;
} 
while (!done);

// Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();}
```

Comment: This helps a lot! If you can make it to also add the text to the final nsdata then your answer works!!!!

Comment: For the text, refrence my answer in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940725/draw-text-from-uitextview-to-pdf-as-it-is/8997636#8997636)

Comment: You only want the rects and NOT the page?

Comment: Ok, see updated code above, this will give you the page, the text and the image in one package.

Comment: how do i convert [self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName] to nsdata to print

Comment: I used this: [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName]; did I do something wrong??? Look at my ss shot I uploaded.

Comment: I am not sure about the "print" method you are using, I am not familiar enough with it.  I use the QuickLook framework in association with the QLPreviewController class and Apple's DirectoryWatcher class, this is all handled for you in a much more elegant way. Check [This Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Listings/Classes_DirectoryWatcher_m.html) and [This Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)