# Draw text from uitextview to pdf as it is

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, pdf, uitextview

I have 4 editable uitextviews, user can set its font font color etc. Now i want to draw pdf of these textviews, but using [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()] method causes to lose its quality, so i cannot use this method, instead i am iterating over subviews and drawing the text in pdf. Now my problem is that for some textviews text is printed correctly in pdf,but for other textviews text is not drawn in proper position.This is my code to draw pdf from textview.
         NSArray *arrayOfsubviews=[self.view subviews];

```
for (int i=0; i<[arrayOfsubviews count]; i++) {

    if ([[arrayOfsubviews objectAtIndex:i]isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {

        UITextView *texts=[arrayOfsubviews objectAtIndex:i];


        CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)texts.font.fontName, texts.font.pointSize,NULL);
        CGColorRef color = texts.textColor.CGColor;

        NSDictionary *attributesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        (__bridge id)ctFont, (id)kCTFontAttributeName,
                                        color, (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,nil];


        NSAttributedString *stringToDraw = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:texts.text
                                                                           attributes:attributesDict];
        CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef) stringToDraw);



        CGRect rect=CGRectMake(texts.frame.origin.x,916-texts.frame.origin.y-texts.frame.size.height, texts.frame.size.width, texts.frame.size.height);


        CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathAddRect(pathRef, NULL,rect);
        CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0),pathRef, NULL);


        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0,916); 
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);


        CTFrameDraw(frameRef, context);


        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        CGPathRelease(pathRef);


    }
   }
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this to draw my text, works fairly well.. maybe it can point you in the right direction.

```
#define kBorderInset 20.0
#define kMarginInset 10.0

- (void) drawText{
CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

NSString *textToDraw = @"Your Text Here";
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font
                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) 
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 350.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

[textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect 
              withFont:font
         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
             alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use drawInContext: instead of renderInContext:. renderInContext will rasterize the text, drawInContext write encode it as editable, resolution-independent text.

Answer (score 0):

Some looses of quality or blurry views are because of the frame. The vales for locate a frame in the screen are CGFloat, so you could have a frame located in the point (0.5, 5.7), obviously this dowsn't have any sense and the point.x must be 0 or 1. Decimal values confuse the Operative System, so it's recommend to ensure that frames have always values with no decimal numbers.

You can ges some more information here: http://www.cobiinteractive.com/blog/2011/06/objective-c-blurry-uiview/ or here: http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiview-blurred-blurry-view/